# How to read value of an array that has been sent from a php script

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

Okay so I have a txt file.

I turn the data of the txt file into an array.

```
$lines = file($filename);
```

Then send the data back to the client ($filename is determined through ajax)

```
print_r( array_values( $lines ));
```

I retrieve the data from ajax

```
    success: function(docinfo){
        alert(docinfo);
    }
```

And I get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 123
    [2] => 455
    [3] => 325
    [4] => 33
    [5] => 3
)
```

but when I want to access the values of the array

```
console.log(docinfo[0]);//which represents the first line of my txt file
```

I get "A" which is the first letter of "Array". not the value of docinfo[0] which I want.

Is there a way where I can send the array and retrieve the values so I can use them the way I want?

Comment: print_r is for debug output. it's purely a string-based format, and it's NOT intended to be used for passing data around. you want json_encode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't understand PHP's object format, you need to convert PHP's object into a form that a javascript parser can understand. We call that serializing, and javascript's format is called JSON.

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array_values($lines));
?>
```

this will give you something *like*:

```
  [
    1,2,3,4,5
  ]
```

Then you can change your onsuccess function to parse the JSON that PHP sent back:

```
success: function(docinfo){
    infoparsed = JSON.parse(docinfo)
    alert(docinfo[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried printing the array with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) ?

```
echo json_encode(array_values($lines));
```